# Oracle invalid trigger ORA-04098

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I cannot figure out where is the problem. here is my trigger
my produkt table has attributes: produktid, name, manufacturing_price, sale_price
i am trying to make sale price 1.1 value of manu price

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "predajna_cena" 
AFTER update of "MANUFACTURING_PRICE" on "PRODUKT"
begin
UPDATE PRODUKT SET SALE_PRICE = MANUFACTURING_PRICE*1.1;
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "predajna_cena" ENABLE;
```

apex is showing Object Status   INVALID

and i cannot change manufacturing price
error ORA-04098: trigger ' '  is invalid and failed re-validation

thanks

Comment: while compiling check with `SHOW ERRORS` option

Comment: If that factor (relation) is always valid you could use a virtual column instead.

Comment: Thou probably nothing to do with your problem: Do you explicitly _want_ your trigger-name in lower case (which is achieved by the double quotes)? Oracle standard would be (pseudo) case-insensitive by converting everything to upper implicit. You should only use case-sensitive naming if you have to/want to.

Comment: just try recompiling the trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "predajna_cena" 
AFTER update of "MANUFACTURING_PRICE" on "PRODUKT"
begin
UPDATE PRODUKT SET SALE_PRICE = MANUFACTURING_PRICE*1.1;
end;
/
```

If you were able to make this trigger to work, it will update *all* prices after *each and every* update of the table `"PRODUKT"`. Probably not what you want.

For such case, you should use a `BEFORE UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger, changing the product price before inserting it `:NEW."SALE_PRICE" = :NEW."MANUFACTURING_PRICE"*1.1`.

Something like that maybe:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "predajna_cena" 
> BEFORE UPDATE OF "MANUFACTURING_PRICE" ON "PRODUKT"
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>   :NEW.SET SALE_PRICE := :NEW.MANUFACTURING_PRICE*1.1;
> END;
> ```
>
> <sup>Untested. Beware of typos!</sup>

---

Depending your needs an other option would use a virtual column instead of a trigger to achieve the same result.

> ```
> DROP TRIGGER "predajna_cena";
> ALTER TABLE "PRODUKT" DROP COLUMN "MANUFACTURING_PRICE";
> ALTER TABLE "PRODUKT" ADD "MANUFACTURING_PRICE" 
>                       GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("SALE_PRICE" * 1.1) VIRTUAL;
> ```
>
> <sup>Untested. Beware of typos!</sup>